# Listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon, ts-node

While working on the backend for a game app I continually run into the error `EADDRINUSE: address already in use`. My only option when this happens is to completely stop and re-build the app.

Specifically, this is a big problem when I am testing/playing with changes made to the game. Ex: load up the game on local, make an edit in the code, server automatically restarts when code is edited, test changes in game, edit code again to tweak it, reload, etc... When I am in this development loop (almost constantly restarting the server on local) it doesn't take long before I run into this issue. Any solutions?

Possibly Related Packages:

```
Node.js: v12.16.3
"ws": "6.2.1",
"typescript": "^3.9.6",
"express": "4.17.1",
"nodemon": "1.18.9",
"ts-node": "7.0.1",
```

I use nodemon with `ts-node app.js` command to run the server.

Comment: What node server library are you using? What commands are you using to run your development server? What does the error message look like in context. This shouldn't have anything to do with typescript, but instead it's about how your node server starts and restarts itself.

Comment: The error simply means an application is already using the port you're trying to use.

Comment: @AlexWayne edited the original post to include this information. Let me know if anything else is missing and if you have any specific recommendations.

Comment: @GirkovArpa this is the only app running on the sever and the error only shows up when the server is continually restarted during development. I assume it has something to do with the server not shutting down properly before restarting but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: **rtm: [delay](http://adilapapaya.com/docs/nodemon/#delayingrestarting)**